# tinyMCE removes all html tags inside

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, tinymce

I am working on laravel project where in i have to make 
CMS which requires tinyMCE , in tinyMCE while adding contents
like uploading images,links,change color of fonts works perfect
and gets store the way it should be in database but when i fetch the 
record from database and put it in tinymce all html tags are removed
or stripped and it displays the plain content that is text ,
I have tried all possible solutions but none of them have given me desired 
result

Any Kind of Help would be appreciated !!

this is my TinyMCE Config file

```
var editor_config = {

    selector: "textarea#page_content",
    plugins: [
      " advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
      "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
      "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
      "emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern bbcode"
    ],
    toolbar1: `insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify 
    | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image media`,
    toolbar2: 'print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons | fontsizeselect',

   style_formats: [
            {title: 'Open Sans', inline: 'span', styles: { 'font-family':'Open Sans'}},
            {title: 'Arial', inline: 'span', styles: { 'font-family':'arial'}},
            {title: 'Book Antiqua', inline: 'span', styles: { 'font-family':'book antiqua'}},
            {title: 'Comic Sans MS', inline: 'span', styles: { 'font-family':'comic sans ms,sans-serif'}},
            {title: 'Courier New', inline: 'span', styles: { 'font-family':'courier new,courier'}},
            {title: 'Georgia', inline: 'span', styles: { 'font-family':'georgia,palatino'}},
            {title: 'Helvetica', inline: 'span', styles: { 'font-family':'helvetica'}},
            {title: 'Impact', inline: 'span', styles: { 'font-family':'impact,chicago'}},
            {title: 'Symbol', inline: 'span', styles: { 'font-family':'symbol'}},
            {title: 'Tahoma', inline: 'span', styles: { 'font-family':'tahoma'}},
            {title: 'Terminal', inline: 'span', styles: { 'font-family':'terminal,monaco'}},
            {title: 'Times New Roman', inline: 'span', styles: { 'font-family':'times new roman,times'}},
            {title: 'Verdana', inline: 'span', styles: { 'font-family':'Verdana'}}
        ],
      valid_elements : 'img[src]',
      entity_encoding: "raw",
        extended_valid_elements : "em[class|name|id]",
        valid_children : "+body[style], +style[type]",
        apply_source_formatting : false,               
        verify_html : false,                           
     file_browser_callback : function(field_name, url, type, win) {
      var x = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientWidth;
      var y = window.innerHeight|| document.documentElement.clientHeight|| document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientHeight;

      var cmsURL = editor_config.path_absolute + 'laravel-filemanager?field_name=' + field_name;
      if (type == 'image') {
        console.log("Hip Hip Hurray");
        cmsURL = cmsURL + "&type=Images";
      } else {
        cmsURL = cmsURL + "&type=Files";
      }

      tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
        file : cmsURL,
        title : 'Filemanager',
        width : x * 0.8,
        height : y * 0.8,
        resizable : "yes",
        close_previous : "no"
      });
    }
  };

  tinymce.init(editor_config);
```

and in blade html file

```
 <textarea name="page_content" class="form-control" id="page_content" >
  {!!$page->page_content!!}
 </textarea>
```

and if this content is put outside tinymce then it displays
exactly the way i want i.e the image ,links does not get stripped off !!

Answer (score 0):

You are using the option [`valid_elements`](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-filtering/#valid_elements) which overrides the existing valid elements. You config makes it so that only `img[src]` tags are allowed. So when saved, all tags that are not `img[src]` are removed from your content.

You should use [`extend_valid_elements`](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-filtering/#extended_valid_elements) to add more valid elements to the existing object.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply
i have added this in my tinymce config now
valid_elements : '\*[\*]', which means allow all elements
but this also does not work !! :(

Comment: yes all tags are removed but it allows <p> tags but images,links,etc are removed !!

Comment: the strange part is if i put the content outside tinymce , it works fine  if i put it within div tags it works but the problem arises only when i try to put content inside tinyMCE ...this is where i am stuck !!